# How to succesfully install Kali Linux 2.0 on a MacBook Pro retina (2015)?

Tags: linux, macos, macbook, kali-linux

**I want to install Kali Linux 2.0 on my MacBook Pro Retina (2015).**

I followed the offical doc/tutorial, but I cannot make it work. Problems:

> 1. After installing refind, I am booting via alt-Key the bootloader from OS X
> 2. I am choosing EFI (as described)
> 3. Then I come to the rEFInd screen, where I choose Windows.
> 4. There I get an error with: `Legacy folder not found.`

I came across many problems from [MacBook 2015 users](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26494-HELP-Kali-Linux-Macbook-Pro-2015).

> Can somebody give me feedback/advice/help on how to succesfully create
>   a Dual Boot between OS X and Kali Linux 2.0 on a 2015 MacBook?

Comment: Please use the following link: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26670-Kali-2-0-Installation-Tips-for-Macbook-Pro-2015-Retina

Comment: I installed a macbook pro with kali 2.0 by following this guide without any issues
http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware